# Is there a algorithm to extract the minimum number of Cartesian products from a set of formulas?

Tags: algorithm, math, cartesian-product

For example, we have a set of formulas as below:

```
B*2*j
B*3*i
B*3*j
C*2*j
C*3*i
C*3*j
D*2*i
D*2*j
D*3*i
D*3*j
```

And we could have three Cartesian products to represent the formulas above:

```
D*(2+3)*(i+j)
(B+c)*3*(i+j)
(B+C)*2*j
```

So the total number is 3. And we could also have:

```
3*(B+C+D)*(i+j)
2*(B+C)*D
2*D*(i+j)
```

which is also 3.

I wanna ask that is there a algorithm to determine the minimum number of Cartesian products from a set of formulas? And also come up with these products?

Comment: You might want to post that on http://math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: [Please refrain from posting the same question on multiple SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). If you wish to move a question to another site, rather flag it and ask that it be migrated, or simply delete it and reask it on the appropriate site.

Comment: I prefer my question appear on both sites. Because, this question may have a related algorithm in computer science.

Comment: If you really intend the numbers (2 and 3) to be treated as uncombinable quantities, please rename them to letters (e.g. x and y).  As it stands, they only confuse matters by seeming to be able to be combined (e.g. if your formulas were terms in a sum, `B*2*j` and `B*3*j` could be combined into `B*5*j`, and the product formula `D*(2+3)*(i+j)` could be simplified to `D*5*(i+j)`).

Comment: Also I guess that only individual factors can appear in "sum factors", right?  Otherwise you can simply form a single formula that sums together all the terms: `B*2*j + B*3*i + ... + D*3*j`.

Comment: BTW the second term in your second answer to your example problem needs to have `*j` appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll write a set of formulas as terms separated by `+`, since the transformation you're looking for makes sense algebraically (apart from the fact that you don't want to combine numbers like `2+3` into `5`).

The basic operation that you have available is **factorising**: combining two terms like `ABC+ABD` into `AB(C+D)`.  Based on your comment, you can only generate new factors that consist of a sum of single-factor terms, like `C+D` in the previous example; you're not allowed to factorise e.g. `ABCD+ABDE` into `AB(CD+DE)`.

**You can factorise 2 k-factor terms if and only if they share exactly k-1 factors.**  (E.g. k=3 in my `ABC+ABD` example.)  Every such factorisation reduces the number of terms in the set by 1: 2 are removed and 1 is added back in.

Doing this multiple times works when combining 3 or more terms: `ABC+ABD+ABE` can first be factorised into `AB(C+D)+ABE` and then those 2 terms factorised again into `AB(C+D+E)`.  Notice that it doesn't matter in which order we list terms in a sum or factors in a product, and nor does it matter in which order we perform factorisation steps when building a factor containing 3 or more terms.

We can then frame the problem as a search problem in a graph, in which the start vertex corresponds to the original formula (`B*2*j + B*3*i + ... + D*3*j` in your example) and from each vertex v there emanate arcs to its child vertices, which each correspond to the result of performing some factorisation on v.  v will have a child vertex for each possible factorisation that could be performed on it; if there are m terms in v, then this means it could have up to m(m-1)/2 children in the worst case, because it could be that all m terms share a full complement of k-1 factors, meaning that any pair of them could be combined.

If a vertex has no pair of terms that can be combined via factorisation then it is a "leaf" -- it has no children, and can't be processed further.  What we want to find is a leaf vertex that has the fewest number of terms.  Since every factorisation, corresponding to an arc in the graph, reduces the number of terms by 1, this is equivalent to searching for a deepest-possible vertex.  This can be done using DFS or BFS.  Note however that the same expression (vertex) can be generated many times over using this approach, so it will be crucial for performance to maintain a hashtable `seen` that records all expressions that have already been processed; then if we visit a vertex, try to generate a child for it, and see that this child is already in `seen`, we avoid visiting this child a second time.

To mitigate against the phenomenon of the same expression being generated via multiple different orderings of the same set of factorisations, you can add a rule: *order* v's child factorisations somehow, so that if there are n children they correspond to factorisations 1, 2, ..., n in this ordering, and record in a separate "already skipped" field in each child vertex the set of *earlier* (in the ordering) factorisations that were skipped over to generate this child.  Then, when visiting a vertex, avoid generating any of its "already skipped" factorisations as children, since doing so would create a vertex that is identical to some other existing vertex (by performing the same pair of operations in reverse order).

There are probably other speedups available that will reduce the number of duplicate vertices that are generated in the first place, but this should be enough to get results for small problems.

Comment: What's the time complexity of this algorithm? Looks like it has lots of branches for every vertex.

Comment: @injoy: If there are n possible (partial) factorisations, then without the "already skipped" idea, it should visit each of them once, but it also spends time generating up to O(m^2) children per node, all of which may be discarded due to having been seen before.  n could be as large as the number of labelled trees on m leaves.  With "already skipped", it should be possible to avoid generating some or all children that get discarded by `seen`, though I don't know how much.

Comment: Hi, @j_random_hacker, the penultimate paragraph is talking about the implementation of the 'seen' hashtable? Or is it a totally different thing?

Comment: @injoy: No, the penultimate paragraph is talking about a second way to reduce the total time, by trying to avoid generating some children in the first place.  (`seen` means that a child that has already been processed won't be processed a second time, but it still has to get generated first before it can be found in `seen` and then discarded.)

Comment: thanks your help! I just couldn't understand this way. Could you give me an example?

Comment: And btw, I implemented the algorithm using C++. It works OK when the number of factors is small. But when the factors reach 13, the execution time is so long that I have to terminate the program.

Comment: Take for example the input `ABC+ABD+ABE`.  This generates 3 children: `AB(C+D)+ABE`, `AB(C+E)+ABD` and `AB(D+E)+ABC`.  Let's assign an order to pairs of original terms, e.g. `ABC+ABD` < `ABC+ABE` < `ABD+ABE`.  Now when we create the first child, we record alongside it that the highest (in terms of the order above) pair used in constructing it is `ABC+ABD`.  Then we we create *its* child `AB(C+D+E)`, we look at all the additional combinations this implies, namely `ABC+ABE` and `ABD+ABE`, and ask whether any of them is lower than the highest pair used in construction so far. ...

Comment: ... The answer is "no", so we go ahead and create this child (recording alongside it that the highest pair used in construction so far is `ABD+ABE`).  OTOH when we create the root's second child `AB(C+E)+ABD`, we record that its highest pair is `ABC+ABE`.  When we try to create *its* child `AB(C+D+E)`, we see that this implies the additional pairs `ABC+ABD` and `ABD+ABE`; but the first of these is lower than `ABC+ABE`, so we discard this child.  Similarly for the root's third child.  However, I'm not actually sure that this is gonna be faster than just using the hashtable.

Comment: The algorithm I described in my answer is basically a brute-force search through all Steiner trees on m labelled vertices, so yes it's slow -- it takes *worse than exponential* time.  I hesitate to suggest that the problem is NP-hard, especially in light of LutzL's apparent insight (which was over my head I'm afraid), but after thinking about it for a while I haven't been able to come up with any poly-time algorithm.  Of course if you're happy with just a "very good" answer instead of all optimal answers, it's easy to think of some good heuristics.

Comment: OK, I get your idea now, thanks! Meanwhile, I have a new idea to decrease the search domain (or arcs in the graph): for every node, we record the search index of its parent, and then we search the current node starting from this index. For example, the third child of ABC+ABD+ABE is ABC+AB(D+E). And this node is generated by starting index 1 (ABD). So, when we start searching on this third node, we'll start at index 1. ABC+AB(D+E) has no more factors whose index is higher than 1. So we stop here. Otherwise, we'll generate its child: AB(C+D+E) which is already generated.

Comment: what do you think of this approach?

Comment: @injoy: I'm afraid I don't have time to think about this further, but I think that will work and be simpler and faster than what I suggested :)  (Considering only expressions in which every term has at most 1 factor that is a sum of 2 or more terms, on any path through the search tree you're essentially building up a set of sets of original terms; it's always possible to form a particular set of sets in 1 way, by ordering the original terms and adding them to the right set in that order.)...

Comment: @injoy: ... For this to be a general approach, one thing you would need to demonstrate is that there is a consistent way to extend this ordering when creating child expressions that contain more than 1 factor that is a sum of 2 terms (e.g. producing `A(B+C)(D+E)` from `AB(D+E)` and `AC(D+E)`.)  (An analogy of this applies to my method too, I think.)  I'll let you try to figure that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Write down you sum in matrix form. Then what you are asking for is the rank of that matrix, and a corresponding decomposition into dyadic products. This decomposition is far from unique.

```
            [ 3  5 ]   [ i ] 
[ B C D ] * | 3  5 | * [ j ]
            [ 5  5 ]
```

As one can see, the matrix in the middle has full rank 2

---

If you intend to use 2 and 3 also as variables, then you are asking to decompose a tensor of order 3 into a minimum number of terms that factorize, i.e., that are tensor products of vectors.